# Generalization of Dirichlet distribution over matrix

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, dirichlet-distribution

I know there is generalization of normal distribution of matrix-valued random variable, i.e., [Matrix normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_normal_distribution). I wonder whether there is generalization of Dirichlet distribution that each row or column sums up one, and the rows or columns are not independent of each other. I have searched `matrix Dirichlet Distribution` but can't find anything expected.

Comment: Seems matrix variate Dirichlet distribution is something like that. But it requires a `p*p` positive definite matrix. I wonder whether there are other ones can have arbitrary shape.